# Setf not expanding

Tags: elisp-macros, macroexpansion, setf

I'm trying to modify a member of [lsp--client](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/blob/master/lsp-mode.el#L1515) after registration. So I have something like the following in `use-package`.

```lisp
(message "%s %s" (symbol-function 'lsp--client-new-connection)
  (macroexpand '(setf (lsp--client-new-connection client) '(1))))
(defun tg/lsp-set-new-connection (client)
 (setf
  (lsp--client-new-connection client) '(1)))
```

Then I call `(require 'lsp-mode)`. The output of message above looks correct.

```
#<subr lsp--client-new-connection> (progn (or (progn (and (memq (type-of client) cl-struct-lsp--client-tags) t)) (signal 'wrong-type-argument (list 'lsp--client client))) (let* ((v client)) (aset v 3 '(1))))
```

However, the `setf` inside `tg/lsp-set-new-connection` doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure what the backslashes mean when I display the text of the closure, but if try to run the function, it gives me a `void-function` error at `setf`.

```
(closure (t) (client) (let* ((v client)) (\(setf\ lsp--client-new-connection\) '(1) v)))
```

I can then evaluate the function with `C-x C-e` and it works now and expands as above. So my question is what's going on, and how do I fix it? Note that I'm only using `setf` because that's how it's done in the code linked above. I would be perfectly happy with another solution.

Comment: Your code as pasted into the question works just fine. You must have evaluated some earlier version of the function that had some weird problem. I don’t quite see how you could get the result you did, but something was wrong with it.

Comment: I've restarted emacs a few dozen times while studying this. It's the same behavior every time. I also tried using with-eval-after-load instead of use-package. Still it's the same.

Comment: I put the entire function definition in an eval as a workaround. I'm going to leave this open as I still have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Is whichever library defines that generalized variable loaded at compile time?  You might need to `require` that.  Do that at the top-level first to confirm but, depending on circumstances, one of `(eval-when-compile (require ...))` or `(eval-and-compile (require ...))` might be most appropriate.  I don't use use-package so I can't suggest how to integrate with that.

Comment: I tried requiring cl-lib before. I tried it again at the top-level as you suggested. I'm not compiling my init file. I tried compiling it once just to see and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Oh, if you're not compiling the file then my comments maybe aren't relevant (although sometimes things get byte-compiled internally).  It wasn't `cl-lib` I was referring to, but rather the library which defines `(lsp--client-new-connection ...)` as a generalized variable.  That will most certainly be something in the lsp package.

Comment: It's defined in lsp-mode.el, the file that I linked to. And I'm loading it with (require 'lsp-mode).

Comment: I think I see the problem; `after-load-alist` contains compiled functions. If I manually add to this list instead of using `eval-after-load` or `use-package` which does the same, then it works. Since the struct definition is not yet loaded when the function is compiled, `setf` can't possibly expand correctly. So the eval I added as a workaround really is necessary.

Comment: That sounds right.  Refer back to my initial comment -- if you `require` lsp-mode at the top-level in your file then compilation should work; but you can also `eval-when-compile` or `eval-and-compile` in order to ensure things are loaded as necessary when byte-compilation happens.

Comment: OK, I understand now; `eval-when-compile` works. The key was the part about "sometimes things get byte-compiled internally".